# DataGridView binding to Acces database issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource, dataadapter

I have a DataGridView which is binded to an Acces Database. I can update the database well if I make edits directly in the DataGridView, but if I use something like:

```
dgView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "Some text";
```

It will write the text in the 1st cell at row 0 but then, when I call:

```
dAdapter.Update(dTable);
```

It won't update the database. Instead, the old value is preserved. If I would have edited the code myself and would have written "Some text" by double clicking the cell and typing in it, it would update fine. I know it is a problem ,but in fact I don't know what it is.

Please help, i really need to get this thing done (it is a project for school). Please ask me any further questions you need to help me. Thanks in advance.

Vali

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you update your DataGridView programmatically the way you're doing it, the DataGridView's underlying data source (your DataTable) isn't being notified that it's been changed - so just the UI changes, not your data source.

You can use the [DataGridView.BeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit.aspx) method to fire these events like so:

```
dgView.BeginEdit(false);
dgView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "Some text"; 
dgView.EndEdit();
```

Rather than attempting to update your DataTable programmatically through the DataGridView as you are, a better approach would be to update your DataTable directly.